# questions about MVC architecture in web application

Tags: model-view-controller

I have certain questions since I'm doing a web app, and I feel kinda confused about keeping the mvc structure in a web application without using any frameworks.

Here is the structure of my app.

index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
loginSend();
});
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login">

    Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>
     <input id="send" type="button" value="Enviar">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The loginsend function sends the data to service.php

```
<?php 
include('server/main.php');
$action = $_POST['action'];
switch($action){

    case "loginCheck":
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $users = new users();
        echo $users->loginCheck($username,$password);
    break;

}

?>
```

And the service uses some classes I defined in main.php

```
<?php

class db{

public function conn() {

    try{

        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbname = "eout";        
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpass = "";

        if($conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbhost.";dbname=".$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass)){
            return($conn);
        }

    }

    catch (Exception $e){
        echo "Se ha presentado un error al conectar con la base de datos".$e;            
    }
}
}

class users{

function loginCheck($username, $password) { 

    try{

        $db   = new db();
        $conn = $db->conn();
        $pass_encriptada = md5 ($password); 

        $SQL_LOGIN_CHECK    = "SELECT * FROM users where username='".$username."' and     password='".$pass_encriptada."' and deleted='0'";
        $conn->prepare($SQL_LOGIN_CHECK);
        foreach($check = $conn->query($SQL_LOGIN_CHECK) as $row) {

            $username_check = $row['username'];
            if ($username_check == $username){

                    session_start();

                    $_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                    $_SESSION['namelastname'] = $row['name'] ." ".$row['lastname'];

                    $usertype_id = $row['usertype_id'];

                        if ($usertype_id == 1 ){ //problema
                            $_SESSION['teacher'] = 1;
                            $response = "teacher";
                            $json = json_encode($response);
                            echo $json;
                        }

                        if ($usertype_id != 1 ){ //problema
                            $response = "user";
                            $json = json_encode($response);
                            echo $json;              
                        }
            }         
        }
    }

    catch(Exception $e){

        echo "Se ha presentado un error en loginCheck".$e;

    }

}

}

?>
```

In this case, I understand that index.php its my view, however I have certain doubts about the model/controller part. I understand in my example that the main file is the one that interacts with data, so it must be the model... in my case... its service.php my controller? Since is the one that interacts with the model? I feel kinda confused about this. In case I am wrong. How can I make a controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry man, that's not even MVC-like. You need to learn some OOP, first of all....